# matlab, structure, periodic table creation

Tags: matlab

I have a little trouble with structures in MATLAB. I need to create my own little periodic table and I think I've done quit well so far. But my problem is when I try to add a second element it writes over the first one. How can I fix this? Please take a look at my code, I know its a bit long:D
I'd appreciate if you see any other mistakes. Thanks for help

```
fprintf('Periodic table program - Main menu:\n (1) Add an element; (2) Search for an element; (3) Exit\n');
choose=input('Enter your choice: ');
while choose~=3
if choose==1
    element.name=input('Enter the name of your element: ','s');
    element.symbol=input('Enter the symbol of your element: ','s');
    element.Anumber=input('Enter the atomic number of your element: ');
    while element.Anumber<=0 || mod(element.Anumber,1)~=0
        disp('This is not a positive integer, please enter a valid input!');
        eAnumber=input('Enter the atomic number of your element: ');
    end
elseif choose==2
    fprintf('Search menu:\n (1) By name; (2) By symbol; (3) By atomic number; (4) Main  menu\n');
    S_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
    while S_choice ~=4
    if S_choice==1
        alex=input('Enter the name of the element: ','s');
        if alex~=element.name
            disp('No such element exists!');
        else
            fprintf('Operations menu:\n (1) Show properties; (2) Edit; (3) Main menu\n');
            Op_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
            while Op_choice~=3
                if Op_choice==1
                    element
                elseif Op_choice==2
                    fprintf('Edit menu:\n (1) Edit name; (2) Edit symbol; (3) Edit atomic number; (4) Main menu\n');
                    E_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
                    while E_choice~=4
                        if E_choice==1
                            new_name=input('Enter the new name of the element: ','s');
                            element.name=new_name;
                        elseif E_choice==2
                            new_sym=input('Enter the new symbol of the element: ','s');
                            element.symbol=new_sym;
                        elseif E_choice==3
                            new_anumber=input('Enter the new atomic number: '); 
                            while new_anumber<=0 || mod(new_anumber,1)~=0
                                disp('This is not a positive integer, please enter a valid input!');
                                new_anumber=input('Enter the new atomic number: ');
                            end
                            element.Anumber=new_anumber;
                        end
                     fprintf('Edit menu:\n (1) Edit name; (2) Edit symbol; (3) Edit atomic number; (4) Main menu\n');
                     E_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
                    end            
                end
                fprintf('Operations menu:\n (1) Show properties; (2) Edit; (3) Main menu\n');
                Op_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
            end
        end
    elseif S_choice==2
        lugano=input('Enter the symbol of the element: ','s');
        if lugano~=element.symbol
            disp('No such element exists!');
        else
            fprintf('Operations menu:\n (1) Show properties; (2) Edit; (3) Main menu\n');
            Op_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
            while Op_choice~=3
                if Op_choice==1
                    element
                elseif Op_choice==2
                    fprintf('Edit menu:\n (1) Edit name; (2) Edit symbol; (3) Edit atomic number; (4) Main menu\n');
                    E_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
                    while E_choice~=4
                        if E_choice==1
                            new_name=input('Enter the new name of the element: ','s');
                            element.name=new_name;
                        elseif E_choice==2
                            new_sym=input('Enter the new symbol of the element: ','s');
                            element.symbol=new_sym;
                        elseif E_choice==3
                            new_anumber=input('Enter the new atomic number: '); 
                            while new_anumber<=0 || mod(new_anumber,1)~=0
                                disp('This is not a positive integer, please enter a valid input!');
                                new_anumber=input('Enter the new atomic number: ');
                            end
                            element.Anumber=new_anumber;
                        end
                     fprintf('Edit menu:\n (1) Edit name; (2) Edit symbol; (3) Edit atomic number; (4) Main menu\n');
                     E_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
                    end 
                end
                  fprintf('Operations menu:\n (1) Show properties; (2) Edit; (3) Main menu\n');
                  Op_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
            end
        end
    elseif S_choice==3
        niang=input('Enter the atomic number of the element: ');
        if niang~=element.Anumber
            disp('No such element exists!');
        else
            fprintf('Operations menu:\n (1) Show properties; (2) Edit; (3) Main menu\n');
            Op_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
            while Op_choice~=3
                if Op_choice==1
                    element
                elseif Op_choice==2
                    fprintf('Edit menu:\n (1) Edit name; (2) Edit symbol; (3) Edit atomic number; (4) Main menu\n');
                    E_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
                    while E_choice~=3
                        if E_choice==1
                            new_name=input('Enter the new name of the element: ','s');
                            element.name=new_name;
                        elseif E_choice==2
                            new_sym=input('Enter the new symbol of the element: ','s');
                            element.symbol=new_sym;
                        elseif E_choice==3
                            new_anumber=input('Enter the new atomic number: ');
                            while new_anumber<=0 || mod(new_anumber,1)~=0
                                disp('This is not a positive integer, please enter a valid input!');
                                new_anumber=input('Enter the new atomic number: ');
                            end
                            element.Anumber=new_anumber;
                        end
                     fprintf('Edit menu:\n (1) Edit name; (2) Edit symbol; (3) Edit atomic number; (4) Main menu\n');
                     E_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
                    end
                end
                fprintf('Operations menu:\n (1) Show properties; (2) Edit; (3) Main menu\n');
                Op_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
            end
        end
    end
    fprintf('Search menu:\n (1) By name; (2) By symbol; (3) By atomic number; (4) Main menu\n');
    S_choice=input('Enter your choice: ');
    end
end
fprintf('Periodic table program - Main menu:\n (1) Add an element; (2) Search for an  element; (3) Exit\n');
choose=input('Enter your choice: ');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of structures to hold the different elements. Try something like the following:

```
element = struct
i = 1;

element(i).name = 'oxygen'
element(i).symbol = 'O'

i = i + 1
element(i).name = 'carbon'
element(i).symbol = 'C'
```

Comment: i can put them in a cell array but they are in 1x1 structure form.

Comment: i need to access in the structure forms aswell, cant figure out:(